# Best practices for modifying JavaScript primitive types

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to call a custom method on a string primitive without modifying the native `String` object.

```
String.prototype.addOne = function() { return this.length + 1};

let str = new String('abc')
str.addOne() // 4
```

The problem with the above code is that new strings will also have the new method, and the above method creation may override other primitive modifications made inside libraries, or other areas of the code base, for example:

```
String.prototype.addTwo = function() {return  this.addOne + 1}
str.addTwo() // 5

String.prototype.addOne = function() { return this.length + 10};
str.addOne() // 13
str.addTwo() // 14, oops
```

Are there any solutions that allow me to create a clone of a `String` Object where i can safely modify its prototype without having to mutate the native global `String` object?

EDIT:

I am specifically asking if there is a way to do this allows me to add methods to a **Primitive String** some have suggested extending the String class, adding a method and then returning a `String` Object. However, this is not the same as a primitive string Object. I would basically like to be able to call custom methods like this :

```
class CustomString extends String{
  someMethod(){
    return 'someValue'
  }
}

let str = '123'
str.someMethod() // '123'                                             <<< this

let str2 = new CustomString('123')
str2.someMethod() // CustomString { [Iterator] 0: '4', 1:'5'. 2: '6'} <<< not this
```

This works, but then the original problem persists, in that we have mutated the global `String` object

```
String.prototype.someMethod = function() {return 'someValue'}

let str3 = '123'
str3.someMethod() // someValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to make a class that `extends String`:

```js
(() => {
  // In one module:
  class SpecialString extends String {
    addOne() {
      return this.length + 1
    }
  }

  const str = new SpecialString('abc');
  console.log(str.addOne()) // 4
})();

(() => {
  // In another module:
  class SpecialString2 extends String {
    addTwo() {
      return  this.addOne() + 1
    }
    addOne() {
      return this.length + 10
    }
  }
  const str = new SpecialString2('abc');
  console.log(str.addTwo());

  console.log(str.addOne());
  console.log(str.addTwo());
})();
```

Comment: I've modified the question to take into account your answer, please check the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subclass:

```js
class CustomString extends String{
  addOne(){...}
}
```

And then simply:

```js
new CustomString("asd").addOne()
```

This class will be very similar to `String`, but you can create additional properties without conflicting with the primitive strings and the native `String` class.
Even `instanceof` will work with it as well:

```js
new CustomString() instanceof String //true
```

But note that you won't be able to create primitive strings with this constructor:

```js
String(1)       //"1"
CustomString(1) //Error
```

---

**EDIT:** According to the edit to the question:

After a lot of messing around, I've found the way to patch properties to primitives' prototypes without affecting their constructors:

```js
function CustomString(from){
  let string
  if(new.target){ //Whether or not was called as constructor
    string = new String(from)
  }else{
    string = String(from)
  }
  Object.assign(Object.getPrototypeOf(string),CustomString.prototype)
  return string
}
//Add your custom properties like this:
CustomString.prototype.addOne=function(){return this.length+1}

//Without new, creates a primitive string
const primitiveCustomString = CustomString('asd')

//With new, creates a string object
const objectCustomString = new CustomString('asd')

console.log(primitiveCustomString) //"asd"
console.log(objectCustomString)    //String{0:"a",1:"s",2:"d",addOne(){...}}

console.log(primitiveCustomString.addOne()) //4
console.log(objectCustomString.addOne())    //4

//You can even concatenate it together with normal strings, the custom properties still remain
console.log(("asd" + primitiveCustomString + "asd").addOne()) //10
console.log(("asd" + objectCustomString    + "asd").addOne()) //10
```

Comment: i've updated the question to account for some details i missed in regards to this answer

Comment: @JamesWilkinson I'm afraid of that's impossible without modifying the native `String` class' prototype...

Comment: is there not a way to clone the `String` object and modify that new `String` object without affecting the global `String` object?

Comment: @JamesWilkinson It's possible to create a new class with custom properties and configuration, but you can't create a **new primitive type**, and primitive strings will **always** have the prototype of the *native* `String`.

Comment: Gah, that sucks. Is there not a way to at-least scope the access of prototype methods to only be within a certain block or closure? would you also be able to point me to any resources to find out more information about this issue? thanks

Comment: @JamesWilkinson Again, no. Scopes exist only in the context of *variables*, but not of *object's properties*. If you mutate an object anywhere, it will be modified everywhere.

Comment: @JamesWilkinson You'll probably have to familiarize yourself with the use of objects instead of primitives for this purpose. Remember, primitives weren't designed to have properties.

Comment: @JamesWilkinson I've solved it: after a lot of messing around, I've found the way to patch properties to primitives' prototypes without affecting their constructors! I've edited my answer, look at it now!

Comment: Unfortunately, this still modifies the native String prototype, try calling addOne() on any instance of `String` and it still has the method :( I think whats happening here is that you are adding a method to the prototype that `String` delegates to, and then creating a `CustomString` that also delegates to that prototype, so calling `CustomString.prototype` and `String.prototype` would be pointing to the same prototype thus giving the `String` object access to the `addOne()` method

Comment: @JamesWilkinson Oops, I haven't noticed that it still modifies `String`'s prototype. Then, there's **really no way.** Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a factory-function.

```
function addoneable_string(s) {
  let ns = new String(s);
  ns.addOne = function() { return this.length + 1};
  return ns;
}

let s = addoneable_string("1");
console.log( s.addOne() );
```

Comment: Doesn't work: TypeError: (intermediate value).addOne is not a function

Comment: I changed the '1' to a `new String('1')` and it runs correctly, but still doesn't solve the problem, please check the edits to the original question :)

Comment: You're right, it only works with String-objects, I updated the answer.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid this time you must decide wether you want to keep the cake or eat it. You can't expect a primitive string to support what a full object does. The only reason you can call methods on primitives is because JS silently wraps that for you into a String object. Why are you trying to avoid String objects? Are you worried about an overhead or something?

Comment: Im trying to create an API wrapper that returns strings, but if another method is called on top of that string, it will operate on it like a method should. But if a method is not provided it would just return the string. e.g, `search('123')` should be a method that returns a query string `search?q=123` but then i want to be able to add an optional method like `search(123).where({x:5})` to return something like `search?q=123&x=5`. I could just return a string object that calls an `exec()` function at the end of each call to convert the string object to a string primitive, but its less pretty :(